# how to do mod_cluster or mod_jk cluster for jboss eap 6.1

Tags: java, apache, jboss-eap-6, mod-jk, mod-cluster

I have two jboss node in same machine with different port and I installed apache server and configured the mod_cluster in apache/conf/httpd.conf as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
 <Directory>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
 </Directory>
<Location /mod_cluster_manager>
    SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Location> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Could you please help me what else I need to configure in both jboss eap **standalone-ha.xml** and any other configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

In  configuration files specify apache server details:

subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:1.2">
mod-cluster-config proxy-list="10.10.10.10:6666"  advertise="false" connector="ajp">

Add the proxy-list attribute in the standalone-ha.xml to include httpd's mod_cluster listen ip set above: